# Find point on circle given point inside circle

Tags: geometry, circles

How can I find the point on the circumference of the circle (A) that is intersected by the line from the center through a point inside the circle. Only the radius, center, and position of the point inside the circle is provided, not the angle.

[image]
 *(Image is not to scale)*

Comment: Point $A$ is the intersection of the circle with the line $y=\dfrac{25}{60}x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $O(0,0)$ the centre of the circle. The equation of the circle is:
$$x^2+y^2=150^2$$
And the equation of the line $OA$ is:
$$y=\frac{60}{25}x=\frac{12}{5}x$$
To find the coord of the point $A$, you have to solve this system of two equations in two unknows:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x^2+y^2=150^2
\\ y=\frac{12}{5}x
\end{matrix}\right.$$
There are two different solutions: $A_0\left(-\frac{750}{13},-\frac{1800}{13}\right) \lor A_1\left(\frac{750}{13},\frac{1800}{13}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

For any point $p(p_1,p_2)\neq(0,0)$ (not necessarily inside the circle) multiply the unit vector in direction $p$ with circle's radius to obtain
$$\frac{(p_1,p_2)}{\sqrt{p_1^2+p_2^2}}\cdot150.$$